# can't bind this to function

Tags: javascript, events

I have a DOM element btn and have function with setTimeout which listens on this element.
I want to  remove my listener while function is running to prevent multiple calls of setTimeout and time overlapping, but this in my callback function is window? I tried to use bind but it's not working

```
const checkTable = () => {
  this.removeEventListener('click', checkTable);
  console.log(this); // i get "window"
  setTimeout(() => {
     //some code
  }, 3000);
};

const app = () => {
  const checkBtn = document.querySelector('.check-btn');
  checkBtn.addEventListener('click', checkTable.bind(checlBtn))
};

app();
```

and the same result with onclick event

Comment: Use `addEventListener` and `function`: https://jsfiddle.net/7tvgen9w/ Arrow functions aren't the cool new way to write functions or a replacement for "traditional" functions, they have a specific purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `.bind()` on an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).  Arrow functions are used to *automatically* use the `this` value from where it's defined.  For this to work, your `checkTable` needs to be a "normal" function.

```
function checkTable() {
  this.removeEventListener('click', checkTable);
  console.log(this); // i get "window"
  setTimeout(() => {
     //some code
  }, 3000);
}
```